# Apache mod_rewrite product brands as subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to display car brands as subdomains with the following structure:

- toyota.domain.com - main brand page
- toyota.domain.com/buy/toyota/avensis/ - product page

I'm trying to use the following apache mod_rewrite rules sequence, but it doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.|mail)(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^buy/(.+)/([^/]+)(?:/)?$ catalog_model.php?make=%1&model=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.|mail)(.+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ catalog_make.php?make=%1 [NC,L]
```

When you open toyota.domain.com - it works just fine, but when you try to access toyota.domain.com/buy/toyota/avensis/ , it still tries to open catalog_make.php intead of catalog_model.php.

What's the right solution in this case?

=====================================================

## UPDATE

Even when I change the first rule to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^buy/toyota/avensis/$ catalog_model\.php?make=$1&model=$2 [NC,L]
```

and open http://toyota.domain.com/buy/toyota/avensis/

Apache still skips this rule and processes catalog_make.php

=====================================================

## UPDATE 2

Even when I change the rule to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(toyota)/$ catalog_model\.php?make=$1 [NC,L]
```

and open http://toyota.domain.com/toyota/  - it still doesn't work.

Comment: Redesign your application using the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Comment: Your updated rewrite rule isn't populating $2, so is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work - just a simple change

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain.\com$
RewriteRule ^buy/(.+)/([^/]+)(?:/)?$ catalog_model.php?make=$1&model=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.|mail)(.+)\.domain.\com$
RewriteRule ^$ catalog_make.php?make=%1 [NC,L]
```

Removed **(.+)** in the second rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*)\.domain\.com$
  RewriteRule ^buy/([^/]*/)?([^/]+)/?$ catalog_model.php?make=%1&model=$2 [NC,L]
```

Should cope with both:

```
toyota.domain.com/buy/avensis
toyota.domain.com/buy/avensis/
toyota.domain.com/buy/toyota/avensis
toyota.domain.com/buy/toyota/avensis/
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: Altered to also cope with: toyota.domain.com/buy/avensis/   as well as: toyota.domain.com/buy/toyota/avensis

Comment: Sorry, still same problem. Whatever is requested - toyota.domain.com or toyota.domain.com/buy/toyota/avensis/ - apache requests catalog_make.php

Comment: Check that your: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}.....  conditions, in front of both rules are identical, as works for me e.g.  ....[rid#7fb4dcaab0a0/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/www/htdocs/] rewrite 'buy/avensis' -> 'catalog_model.php?make=wibble&model=avensis'

Comment: It doesn't make much difference in this case. I've corrected initial post though.

Comment: If you have root access to the server define a RewriteLog file and temporarily set the RewriteLogLevel to 9.  This will indicate why your first rule is failing to match.

Comment: I don't see anything in the log that says about match failure....

Comment: Your updated rule won't work see comment above, also please confirm you are using both the RewriteCond and Rewrite rule in this post.

Comment: I've updated the initial post - still no luck